# React Native TextInput in ListView value by state is stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I have a text input that sets a state value for itself dynamically as you can see.

When typing into the text input, the state does indeed set itself as I am able to console.log the state value and see it. However, the issue is that I set the value={} to that state value and every time I type into the text input quickly, after about 2 mili seconds, the text input resets itself.

These are inside renderRow function by the way.

```
                    <View style={{flex:0.9}}>
                            <TextInput
                                style={styles.commentInput}
                                placeholder="Say something..."
                                placeholderTextColor="gray"
                                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                                //multiline={true}
                                onChangeText={(commentInput) => {this.setState({["comment"+statusData.id]: commentInput})}}
                                value={this.state["comment"+statusData.id]}
                            />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{justifyContent: "center", marginRight: 20}}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.setState({selectedComment:statusData.id,loadingComment:true});setTimeout(this.addComment.bind(this),50);console.log("comment"+statusData.id);console.log(this.state["comment"+statusData.id])}}>
                            <Icon name="md-send" size={25} color="#CCC" />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
```